# Best way for creating and reusing datacontext in ASP .NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, locking, dbcontext, httpcontext

I have read [this](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/avoid-static-variables-in-asp-net/) post and I'm confused about what is the best way for datacontext creation and consumption ?

I always thought that you should use singleton like below (+locking)

```
private static ModelDataContext dataContext=null;
protected static ModelDataContext DataContext
{
  get
  {
       if(dataContext==null)
           dataContext = new ModelDataContext();
       return dataContext;
   }
}
```

However in the article he says shortly:

LINQ DataContexts cache some of the data and changes you make – you can quickly eat up memory if each instance isn’t disposed fairly quickly. TableAdapters hold open SQLConnections for reuse – so if you use enough classes of TableAdapters, you can have enough different static vars to tie up all of your db connections.

and suggests to use the model below

```
protected static ModelDataContext DataContext
{
  get
  {
       if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["ModelDataContext"]==null)
           System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["ModelDataContext"] = new ModelDataContext();
       return (ModelDataContext)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["ModelDataContext"];
   }
}
```

What are your thoughts ?

Comment: I bet it's not good to place your context in `HttpContext`. Either it's not really good to use static property for this, you already mention it. I usually create `DataContext` on each request and dispose it when response sended to client

Comment: Do you find that *creating* a context is a particularly costly operation?  I generally haven't found that to be the case, but perhaps my applications haven't been of high enough volume to notice.  Unless there's a significant performance problem, I would say that you should really be creating and disposing your contexts as a unit of work for any given request being made to the application.  Having a *static* or in any way *shared* database connection in a multi-user application seems like a famously bad idea to me.

Comment: Dependency injection is the way to go. Your context should be in "request" scope (the exact terminology may differ slight from one IoC container to the next). That means the lifetime will be bound to the request: a new instance will be created for each request and disposed when the request completes.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use a Dependency Injection container, such as [ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), to instanciate a new `DataContext` for each web request.